# Debugging AWS SAM in VSCode - Don't stop debugger at wrapper entry file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I've created a AWS SAM project using nodejs14.x. I've been able to get debugging working, but every time I run my program it stops on an AWS wrapper `index.js` file.
[See this link for a picture of the actual file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJYl6.png) It looks like the file is located at `\var\runtime\index.js`. If I press Continue, my program runs fine, and breakpoints in it are stopped at. But it's really annoying to have to press Continue to get past this file every single time I debug.

Does anyone know a way to "ignore" this file when debugging? In [this help page about debugging in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes), it talks about a `stopOnEntry` variable you can set in `launch.json`. However, no Intellisense suggestions appear for `stopOnEntry`, and I'm not sure if aws-sam supports this.

If it helps, here's my `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "aws-sam",
      "request": "direct-invoke",
      "aws": {
        "credentials": "profile:<myemail>"
      },
      "name": "MyLambdaFunction:src/handlers/my-lambda-file.myLambdaFunction (nodejs14.x)",
      "invokeTarget": {
        "target": "code",
        "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/",
        "lambdaHandler": "src/handlers/my-lambda-file.myLambdaFunction",
      },
      "lambda": {
        "runtime": "nodejs14.x",
        "payload": {},
        "environmentVariables": {}
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I asked the same thing, today. Several others have also, and I don't see a working answer anywhere.